# Insert into @tablename in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write the Stored Procedure that take two parameters. One is Identity column and another one about the Name (may be table name)

Table Structure is

```
    ColumnName    DataType
    ----------------------
    ID            BIGINT
    TableName     VARCHAR(100)
```

Stored Procedure that I have written is

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SET_TABLE_VAL] 

@TableName VARCHAR(100),
@ID BIGINT OUTPUT   
    AS
    BEGIN

DECLARE @TableQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(100)

SET @Table = @TableName

SET @TableQuery = 'INSERT INTO @Table(TableName)VALUES(@TableName)'

    SELECT @TableQuery = REPLACE(@TableQuery,'@Table',@TableName)
    SELECT @TableQuery = REPLACE(@TableQuery,'@TableName',@TableName)
SET @ID = @@IDENTITY

EXEC(@TableQuery)

    END
```

This Procedure returns "Invalid Column Name" (at Input TableName) error. I am not able to find what is the mistake in this. Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where's @ProjectName coming from?

Comment: It seems the table you are trying to insert does not have a column called `TableName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much cleaner and safer approach would be something like this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SET_TABLE_VAL]
@TableName VARCHAR(100),     --<-- I would use nvarchar(128) the maximum lenght
@ID BIGINT OUTPUT               -- a table name can be 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TableQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @TableQuery = N'INSERT INTO @Table(TableName) VALUES(@TableName) '
                 + N'SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); '


EXECUTE sp_executesql @TableQuery
                     , N'@TableName VARCHAR(100), @ID BIGINT OUTPUT'
                     , @TableName , @ID OUTPUT

END
```

**@@IDENTITY Vs SCOPE_IDENTITY()**

`@@IDENTITY` will return the last generated Identity number for this table in any connections, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will only return the last generated Identity in this current connection.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem. Combine both Answers working for me. A modifications in your answer is-                               N'INSERT INTO @Table(TableName)VALUES(''@TableName'') '               + N'SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); ' .

Comment: **Muhammed Ali** - Now clear about the return of last Identity. Thanks for make the clarity on Identity

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead...

```
SET @TableQuery = 'INSERT INTO @Table(TableName)VALUES(''@TableName'')'
```

Also you can probably remove

```
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(100)
SET @Table = @ProjectName
```

since it's not being used.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Instead of TableName i put ProjectName. I updated my question.

Comment: **Sam yi** - @Muhammed Ali's answer and your answer solved my problem. The problem I face while trying your answer return the previous identity of the table. Thanks for your Effort for me.